# ASP.NET core Entity Framework null value connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to connect my api to a SQL Server database. I am getting a null connection string value in my startup class. I totally don't know what I am doing wrong. Could you please check and let me know what should I correct? Thank you in advance.

Startup.cs

```
var connectionSettings = Configuration.GetSection("Connection").Get<ConnectionSettings>();

services.AddDbContextPool<Context>(
      options => options
            .UseSqlServer(connectionSettings.ConnectionString));
```

My `appsettings.json` connection is below:

```
"Connection": [
{
  "EFMode": "MSSQL",
  "DatabaseName": "Shop",
  "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Shop;Trusted_Connection=True,MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
}
```

In `Program.cs` (main class):

```
var db = services.GetService<Context>();

if (db != null)
{
    var cs = services.GetService<ConnectionSettings>();
    db.Database.Migrate();

    var dt = services.GetService<DefaultTriggers>();
}
```

And my `Context.cs`:

```
var connectionSettings = config.GetSection("Connection").Get<ConnectionSettings>();

var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionSettings.ConnectionString);

return new Context(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

ConnectionSettings.cs

```
    public class ConnectionSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to have an array of `Connection`?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to show ConnectionSettings. Please find below the code:
    public class ConnectionSettings
  '  {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    }'

Comment: Can you put code in your question? You _can_ edit it.

Comment: I did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to change your settings so that you have a single connection object (note that I've removed the `[` array `]`:

```
"Connection": {
  "EFMode": "MSSQL",
  "DatabaseName": "Shop",
  "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Shop;Trusted_Connection=True,MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
}
```

Or you need to instruct the configuration object to load an array of `ConnectionSettings`:

```
var connectionSettings = Configuration.GetSection("Connection").Get<ConnectionSettings[]>();
var shopConnection = connectionSettings.First(s => s.DatabaseName == "Shop");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify getting the connection string like this:

```
var connectionString = config["Connection:ConnectionString"];
```